# How to replace content with change addEventListener instead of adding

Tags: javascript, replace, addeventlistener, onchange

Hi I have some code where i'm inserting a span on a page each time a change is made to a dropdown item. What i want to achieve is the content inside the span to be changed/replaced each time a change in the dropdown is made. But what I'm currently getting is a new span being created each time instead. An example of how my code looks is below, any help on this would be appreciated.

```js
doSomething.addEventListener('change', function() {
    document.querySelector('.className').insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", "<span>" + somethingDynamic + "</span>");
});
```

Comment: Can you please provide a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). So including the html so we get a better understanding what you are trying to do and what you expect.

Comment: @MarkBaijens I've managed to get it working now using your suggestion of using innerHTML, but inserting a div onto the page prior to the dropdown change so this solution works. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed the span content to be inserted into a certain place on the page so I created a new Div to be inserted onto the page where i needed it and then to replace the content inside it using innerHTML as suggested to get what I needed.

```js
doSomething.addEventListener('change', function() {
    document.querySelector('.className').insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", "<div class='new'></div>");
  document.querySelector('.new').innerHTML =  "<span>"+ dynamicContent + "</span>";
});
```